# How to remove `#HttpOnly_` prefix before MozillaCookieJar load cookies.txt?

Tags: python, cookies, httponly, cookiejar

I use Firefox's extension (cookies.txt) export cookies.txt for python script.
And there is some HttpOnly cookie begins with "#HttpOnly_" was ignored in MozillaCookieJar, just like a comment, e.g.:

```
#HttpOnly_.sample.com    TRUE    /    FALSE    1258200001    value1    111
#HttpOnly_.sample.com    FALSE   /    FALSE    1209905939    value2    222
```

Here is a [issue tracker : MozillaCookieJar ignores HttpOnly cookies](https://bugs.python.org/issue2190) with some code snippets maybe fix the problem like this:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from http.cookiejar import MozillaCookieJar
from contextlib import contextmanager

def fix_cookie_jar_file(orig_cookiejarfile):
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+') as cjf:
        with open(orig_cookiejarfile, 'r') as ocf:
            for l in ocf:
                cjf.write(l[10:] if l.startswith('#HttpOnly_') else l)
        cjf.seek(0)
        yield cjf.name

# the following code is TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not generator
# Ref: https://bugs.python.org/issue2190
MozillaCookieJar(filename=fix_cookie_jar_file('d:/cookies.txt'))
```

How can I fix the `TypeError` ?

Thanks.

update:
the follow code works as expected.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from http.cookiejar import MozillaCookieJar
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os

# Ref: https://bugs.python.org/issue2190
def fix_cookie_jar_file(orig_cookiejarfile):
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', delete=False) as cjf:
        with open(orig_cookiejarfile, 'r') as ocf:
            for l in ocf:
                cjf.write(l[10:] if l.startswith('#HttpOnly_') else l)
        cjf.seek(0)
        return cjf.name

filename = fix_cookie_jar_file(r"d:\cookies.txt")
jar = MozillaCookieJar(filename)
jar.load(ignore_expires = True)

# delete "manually" afterwards
os.remove(filename)

i=0
for ck in jar:
    print("(%d) %s : %s"%(i,ck.name,ck.value))
    i+=1
```

`open()` function can't accept generator as parameter, is there some decorator or wrapper for `open()` function can accept generator as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the issue by modifying the following line:

```
MozillaCookieJar(filename=fix_cookie_jar_file('d:/cookies.txt'))
```

To this:

```
MozillaCookieJar(filename=next(fix_cookie_jar_file('d:/cookies.txt')))
```

Here, we are using `next` to iterate over the elements of the generator, as the first element will be the name of the temporary file, it will work for the `MozillaCookieJar` as it will be receiving just a string instead of the generator itself.

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

I see that you updated the question. I did some refactor to your code to fix the issue. The code works and here it is:

```
from http.cookiejar import MozillaCookieJar
import os

temp_filename = "temp_file.txt"

# Ref: https://bugs.python.org/issue2190
def remove_httponly(cookiejar_file):
  cookies = []
  with open(cookiejar_file, 'r') as cookie_file:
    for line in cookie_file:
      cookies.append(line[10:] if line.startswith('#HttpOnly_') else line)
  with open(temp_filename, 'w') as temp_file:
    temp_file.write(''.join(cookies))
    return True

if remove_httponly("d:/cookies.txt"):
  new_cookie_jar = MozillaCookieJar(temp_filename)
  new_cookie_jar.load(ignore_expires = True)

  # delete "manually" afterwards
  os.remove(temp_filename)

  id = 0
  for cookie in new_cookie_jar:
    print(f"({id}) {cookie.name} : {cookie.value}")
    id += 1
```

**Note:** Don't forget to verify that your `cookies.txt` file is in the right format to be read by `MozillaCookieJar`. Otherwise, another separated error will appear.

Comment: `jar = MozillaCookieJar(filename=next(fix_cookie_jar_file("d:/cookies.txt")))`  get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\some\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp3nw8k2ya'" error

Comment: Hi, what you commented is another error, the answer solves what you asked in the beginning. If you're wondering why do you receive that error. That's because the temporary file you are trying to enter does not exist anymore. When you are definining it you can set this: `with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', delete=False) as cjf:` to prevent the deletion of the file. I just updated my answer.